# author key & custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, author

I am trying to create an author.php page that calls custom post types by the author appearing on that page. My problem is that when using the code below -- which filters for the post type 'video' -- the code outputs all custom post types, not just 'video'. The caveat is when I remove the array's author key and variable `'author' => $author` which then has the effect of allowing the code to output the desired custom post type 'video' but from every author. Any ideas of how to fix this?

**Code used:**

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'audio' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'author'         => $author
    );


    $author_videos = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : while ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : $author_videos->the_post(); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>       
        <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am having a similar problem where I can run a keyword search query and it displays all custom post types but I also need to run queries for a single author and single CTP, for example all Blogs by Joe -- and I cannot figure this out. There are more details in my recently posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637517/combined-search-for-author-custom-post-type/21649345

Answer (score 0):

No need for a new WP_Query, you can modify the default query on `author.php` with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), put the following in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','so20175501_pre_get_posts' );
function so20175501_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_author ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'video' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am have a similar problem here regarding search queries for an author and single custom post type, for example, all blogs by joe:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637517/combined-search-for-author-custom-post-type/21649345 I tried your recommendation above but it didn't work for me. Do you have any other recommendations? More details are on my own question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been trying to solve this myself, and have found that if you use `author__in` with a single-value array for the author ID, then WP_Query seems to treat it differently, giving you the correct result.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => array( 'audio' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'author__in'         => array( $author )
);
```