# Combined Search for Author & Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, search

I have searched questions similar to mine but with no luck finding the answer I need.

I have Authors and I have Custom Post Types (CPT). My search results already display all CPT's -- but, additionally, I need something more specific than that. I need my search function to allow combined queries for a specific Author and specific CPT. For example, all Blogs by Albert Einstein.

This url "/?s=%20&author_name=alberteinstein" returns all posts across CPT's by Albert Einstein.

But if I add "&post_type=blogs" for the full url to filter for the CPT like this:

"/?s=%20&author_name=alberteinstein&post_type=blogs"

it does not filter for just Blogs -- it still returns all CPT's by the Author, same as above.

I need to be able to query for an Author and specific CPT.

This has been driving me crazy for weeks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may help (as worded on the [WordPress Codex post types page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)). Basically, it may be that your custom post type (CPT) isn't registered for archive queries although it is legitimately registered for use as a CPT.

Registering a custom post type does not mean it gets added to the main query automatically. If you want your custom post type posts to show up on standard archives or include them on your home page mixed up with other post types, use the pre_get_posts action hook.

```
// Show posts of 'post', 'page' and 'movie' post types on home page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'movie' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, my CPT's already display in my archive queries. I am looking for something more specific than that. I need to be able to query for a specific CPT and author, like all Blogs by Joe. Right now if I query for that I get all Blogs by Joe plus thousands of units of content from other CPT's such as WebArticles, MagArticles, Video, and Audio by Joe. This means it is impossible for me to view just Blogs by the Author, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: May also be that the CPT isn't registering the author. One potential test for this is whether the author is an available display option when editing that CPT, e.g., as discussed **[in this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-how-to-change-author?replies=4)**. We had this issue with a plugin we use. For now, we're simply modding the DB via webyog when needing to tweak the author id instead of modding the plugin using add_post_type_support() &/or tweaking their register_post_type() call.

Comment: Yeah, the Author is there. I just cant filter for an Author and just one CPT :(

Comment: alright, gotta jet for the day, will take a look at again next week if a solution hasn't otherwise materialized for you.

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much for your recommendations.

Comment: Two clarification questions <br/> <br/>
1. What happens if you query by author id instead of author_name, e.g., ?s=the&author=14&page_type=foo<br/><br/>
2. Are you sure you're using the correct author field to query, e.g, this query, **[http://awesomeispossible.com/?s=the&author_name=caugeri](http://awesomeispossible.com/?s=the&author_name=caugeri)**.

Comment: Hi! Re: question 1. The same result -- I get all CPT's by the author. Re: question 2. I get the exact same result using "author_name" (which searches for the username) as using author (which searches for ID). In each case it returns all CTP's. I can't seem to query for an author and a single CPT :(

Comment: clarifying "author is there" from a couple of comments back - when you edit a post, does the author show on the admin screen, or alternatively stated, can you change author on admin page of that CPT. The author is set when CPT created, however, if registration hook not set, won't be able to edit / query author AFAIK.

Comment: p.s. & what version of WP are you using for the site in question?